# On certain order-automorphisms of the rationals

Tags: co.combinatorics, model-theory, order-theory, automorphism-groups, linear-orders

Consider the rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual order $\leq$. Now let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, such that foreseen with the induced order $\leq$, $(A,\leq)$ is a dense linear order.

Furthermore, suppose that the complement of $A$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finite.

- (@) Does there exist an order-automorphism $\alpha$ of
  $(\mathbb{Q},\leq)$ such that $A \subset \alpha(A) \ne A$ ?

(The condition on $\vert \mathbb{Q} \setminus A \vert$ might be too naive, but I am looking for "as mild as possible" conditions on $A$ so that (@) would be true.)

Comment: Can we answer this using the ideas at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/9901/which-are-the-rigid-suborders-of-the-real-line? E.g. starting from $\mathbb{Q}$, "do the ordinary middle-third construction of the Cantor set, except that whenever you delete the n-th (numbered by level and then left to right, say) middle-third interval leave in exactly n points from that interval. Let's call the resulting set" $\mathbb{Q} \,\backslash\, A$. Would that work?

Comment: Answer to my question in the above comment: no, that does not provide a counterexample; even though $\mathbb{Q} \,\backslash \, A$ is rigid, with no non-trivial isomorphisms, it has structure-preserving maps into itself. Answer to the question in the post: None of the obvious counterexamples work, but I don’t see how to prove it.

Comment: I guess the answer is true, but the argument should deal carefully with the complement, which is not assumed dense and is therefore highly not homogeneous. When $A$ has dense complement it's easy: $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbf{Q},\le)$ acts transitively on dense subsets with dense complement.

Comment: @YCor It’s so far from homogeneous that we’d need a structure theory. Dealing with the complement” is basically proving that any countably infinite linear order has a non-trivial endomorphism.

Comment: @MattF. In fact it's true that every countably infinite linear order has a non-trivial endomorphism. This is an old theorem of Dushnik and Miller (Concerning similarity transformations of linearly ordered sets, Bull. AMS 46 (1940), no. 4, pp. 322–326). See also [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327226/self-embeddings-of-uncountable-total-orders?rq=1). But that result does not suffice to "handle the complement", since an arbitrary endomorphism of the complement of $A$ may fail to extend to an endomorphism of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @YCor : just to be sure: "When  has dense complement it's easy: Aut(,≤) acts transitively on dense subsets with dense complement." How do you define "dense subset" here ?

Comment: @THC Dense in the order topology. So if $(L,\leq)$ is a linear order, a subset $A\subseteq L$ is dense if for all $b< c$ in $L$, if there is any $x\in L$ such that $b<x<c$, then there is some $a\in A$ such that $b<a< c$.

Answer (score -3):

Let $f(x)=2x$ for any rational $x$, and let $A$ consist of all rationals in $(0,1)$.

Comment: wrong original "answer"; another try.

Comment: But the question is...can we make a construction like this for any dense coinfinite A?